# Junit4 Test Suite - Looping and adding test cases dynamically from test suite

Tags: java, junit, junit4, testcase

I have an XML file with many models. 
I'm parsing this XML file in Test Suite and reading each model.
For each model, I want to execute specific list of test cases.

That means, inside a FOR loop in test suite, I have to add test cases dynamically.

---

```
public static TestSuite suite() {
TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
for(condtion){
    if(model1){
         suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(TestCase1.class));
         suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(TestCase2.class));
     }
     elseif(model2){
         suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(TestCase3.class));
         suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(TestCase4.class));
     }
  }
return suite;
}
```

---

But in this scenario, only the test cases for last model in XML is run. It is not dynamically adding test cases and running it for all models.

Then I tried with

JUnitCore.runClasses(TestScoopixModelLoader.class);

inside the for loop. I this scenario, test cases are run dynamically.
But I'm not getting that visual effect in eclipse.(i.e GREEN bar for success, RED bar for failure). This visual effect is not working for Junit TEST RUNNER CLASS

Please suggest me a solution if any one have faced this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own listener and let it print the results (in a textfile, sysout, etc)

```
JUnitCore jCore = new JUnitCore();
jCore.addListener(new CustomListener()) 
JUnitCore.runClasses(TestScoopixModelLoader.class);


 public class CustomListener extends RunListener {
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) {
       System.out.println(failure);
    }

// Rest of the listener methods

 }
```

Listener api:
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html